# Addition of 2 integers

Tags: c#, algorithm, reinventing-the-wheel

I've implemented an algorithm found in a book. It adds 2 positive integers of equal size. How can it be improved? It is assumed that inputted data is always positive integers with an equal number of digits.

**EDIT**
As there are lots of comments regarding the question, I would like to rephrase it. This program tries (yes it tries, could be wrong) to simulate how humans do manual additions of 2 positive integers. This is similar to the technique students learn in (I hope..) primary schools. It is based on the book "Invitation to Computer Science". One obvious improvement to this program is adding validations. What else can be done to improve it?

```
class Program
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Add2Numbers(97,47);
        Console.ReadLine();            
    }



    static void Add2Numbers(int a, int b)
    {
        int carry = 0,sum=0;
        List<int> lstA = new List<int>();
        List<int> lstB = new List<int>();
        List<int> lstSum = new List<int>();

        foreach (var item in GetDigit(a))
        {
            lstA.Add(item);
        }

        foreach (var item in GetDigit(b))
        {
            lstB.Add(item);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < lstB.Count;j++ )
        {
            sum = lstA[j] + lstB[j] + carry;
            if (sum > 9)
            {
                sum = sum - 10;
                carry = 1;
            }
            else
                carry = 0;
            lstSum.Add(sum);
        }

        if (carry > 0)
            lstSum.Add(carry);

        lstSum.Reverse();
        foreach (var item in lstSum)
        {
            Console.Write(item);
        }
    }

    static IEnumerable<int> GetDigit(int number)
    {
        while (number > 0)
        {
            yield return number % 10;
            number = number / 10;
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: The obvious improvement would be `int c = a + b`, therefore some more information on what the goal is would be helpful.

Comment: *"Please ignore the data validation part"* – which validation part? Anyway, an answer can always address *any* aspect of the code in the question.

Comment: I'm trying to simulate how a computer program would attempt to add two integers. Basically trying to implement behind the scene of `int c=a+b`.

Comment: *"I'm open to answer in any programming language."* – not sure what you mean. Here we review your existing code, and that happens to be in C#.

Comment: All I'm looking for is, "can we improve the current code?".

Comment: _It attempts to add 2 positive integers of equal size_ so it doesn't actually adds them... just attempts, right? This means the result is wrong, isn't it?

Comment: Do you mean: I want to add two numbers with the same number of digits together by simulating the method "Long Addition" where you add each "column" together separately? That is what the code appears to do so just checking that's what you meant.

Comment: @RobH you are right.

Comment: How strict is the "equal size"?  One could argue that 12 is the same size as 1234 by writing 12 as 0012.

Comment: A computer does not add the individual digits (0-9).  It instead looks at the individual bits (0-1).

Comment: I found this algorithm in the book "Invitation to Computer Science". I'm trying to implement this in `C#`. Please let's not make it a debate. Thanks.

Comment: The thing it that the ambiguity and lack of information in the question creates a debate, because people can't understand what you are really trying to do and the restrictions that should be considered. So my suggestion would be to make it as clear as possible in the question itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I generally prefer `foreach` to `for`, but in the case where you are using the index variable to iterate through two lists at once, `for` is a pretty good option. I still try to use `.Zip()` instead, as the other answer demonstrated, but sometimes that can get hairy. Here are some smaller improvements that don't involve changes to the overall structure.

- It's always a good idea to use descriptive names

  - I would rename `LstA` to `DigitsOfA` (same for B, and Sum)
  - I would rename `GetDigit` to `GetDigits`
- It's usually<sup>1</sup> a good idea to delay declaration of a variable until it's used

  - A related concept is reducing variable scope; not using a global variable if a local variable will do. This doesn't have any technical impact, but it does have a readability impact: If I see you using a variable but have to scroll up to see how that variable was declared, the flow of my reading has been interrupted. We could call this "spatial scope".
  - Here, this would mean declaring `sum` and `carry` just before the `for` loop, instead of at the top of the function.
  - You could even declare `sum` inside the loop. It does *seem* inefficient to instantiate a new variable every iteration of the loop, but (1) the impact will probably be low, even negligible, (2) you can generally trust the compiler to do [something smart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535846/is-it-better-to-declare-a-variable-inside-or-outside-a-loop/8536197#8536197) (3) if making my program a tiny bit easier to read also makes it a tiny bit slower, that's a trade I'll gladly make every time.
- I usually prefer `var` over explicit types when declaring a variable

  - This is the subject of a fair amount of debate, but here's my reasoning. It's easier for me to read

    ```
    var prices = new Dictionary<Fruit, decimal>();
    var lemon = new Lemon();
    var price = 17.50;
    prices.Add(lemon, price);
    ```

    than

    ```
    Dictionary<Fruit, decimal> prices = new Dictionary<Fruit, decimal>();
    Lemon lemon = new Lemon();
    decimal price = 17.50;
    prices.Add(lemon, price);
    ```

    In the former, the information I immediately want to know (what are the variables' names? how are they used?) all flows nicely down the left edge.
- It's nearly always easier (to write and to read) to use LINQ's `.ToList()` than to call `List.Add()` in a loop.

  - This means you can initialize your lists quite easily as `var digitsOfA = GetDigits(a).ToList();`
- Implicit braces do make your code shorter and prettier, but they are also the source of a very common bug. You write

  ```
  if (awake)
      GetCoffee();
  ```

  then I come along and update your code to

  ```
  if (awake)
      GetCoffee();
      GetBreakfast();
  ```

  All of a sudden I'm eating breakfast while I'm still asleep. And if you're thinking I'd have to be a real bonehead to make that mistake, you're right! But it's a mistake I've made before, it's a mistake that will be made again... And it's a mistake that would be *impossible* if the original code were

  ```
  if (awake)
  {
      GetCoffee();
  }
  ```

  So consider very carefully how likely it is that others might modify your code in the future, or that you might modify it before you have your coffee... I recommend the braces every time.
- You can dodge the whole brace issue, however, by modular arithmetic instead of `if`:

  ```
  carry = sum / 10;
  sum = sum % 10;
  ```
- I quite like the `GetDigits` function as it stands! That's an excellent use of `yield return`, in my opinion.

<sup><sup>1</sup>This advice does not apply to Javascript, thanks to [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)</sup>

Comment: I didn't understand `var digitsOfA = GetDigits(a).ToList();` part. I read MSDN as well. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: [Here's a demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VZmocC). If that doesn't clear things up, maybe the piece that's missing is how [extension methods](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) work in C#. It's worth noting that the implementation of `.ToList()` is probably identical to the code you already have; the extension method just hides that code "under the hood" and gives it a nice name.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for ways to 'modernise' the code you might try some linq bits and pieces.

There should be no need for explicit adding to lists.

As the input numbers are both of the same size, we can easily use `.Zip()` to merge the digits. **Note:** We need to call `.ToArray()` or something else to evaluate the zip before we try to use the `carry` value to add the last digit or else it will not have the correct value.

Adding the last digit is a bit messy but works.

`string.Join()` on the enumeration seems neater than the loop of `Write()` calls, but that is pretty much a matter of personal preference.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var res = AddTwo(97,43);
    System.Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", res.Select(n => n.ToString())));
}


private static IEnumerable<int> AddTwo(int a, int b)
{
    int carry = 0;
    var digits = GetDigits(a).Zip(GetDigits(b), (x,y) => AddWithCarry(x,y, ref carry)).ToArray();

    return digits.Concat( carry == 1 ? new int[]{1} : Enumerable.Empty<int>()).Reverse();

}

private static int AddWithCarry(int a, int b, ref int carry)
{
    var sum = a + b + carry;
    var ret = sum %10;
    carry = (ret == sum) ? 0 : 1;
    return ret;    
}

private static IEnumerable<int> GetDigits(int value)
{
    while(value > 0)
    {
        yield return value%10;
        value /=10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All in all your algorithm works as expected. It exemplifies how addition works in a positional number system with base 10 although it is done in reverse order.

Below I have reviewed your code with some inline comments:

```
// You should return the result instead of writing to the console inside your calculation algorithm
public static List<int> Add2Numbers(int a, int b)
{
  if (a < 0 || b < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("a or b", "One or more arguments are lesser than 0"):

  // Instantiate each variable on separate lines, it is more readable
  int carry = 0;
  int sum = 0;

  // You are doing to much in the same method.
  // In general a method should only do one thing (as a general rule), so create the digit lists in a separate method
  List<int> lstA = GetDigits(a);
  List<int> lstB = GetDigits(b);
  List<int> lstSum = new List<int>();

  for (int j = 0; j < lstB.Count; j++)
  {
    sum = lstA[j] + lstB[j] + carry;
    // The next is OK, but you could use modular/integer division as others have stated
    if (sum > 9)
    {
      sum = sum - 10;
      carry = 1;
    }
    else
      carry = 0;

    lstSum.Add(sum);
  }

  if (carry > 0)
    lstSum.Add(carry);

  lstSum.Reverse();

  return lstSum;
}

static List<int> GetDigits(int number)
{
  // You can do it the "hard" way:
  /*
  List<int> digits = new List<int>();

  foreach (var item in EnumDigits(number))
  {
    digits.Add(item);
  }

  return digits;
  */

  // Or the LINQ-way
  return EnumDigits(number).ToList();

  // LINQ can do many things a lot more elegant than more traditional approaches, so it's good to be familiar with, 
  // but be aware that it often is considerably slower than more traditional ways especially with large data sets.
}

static IEnumerable<int> EnumDigits(int number)
{
  while (number > 0)
  {
    // This is just perfect
    yield return number % 10;
    number = number / 10;
  }
}
```

---

If you want to do it from right to left as one do on paper, it could be something like:

```
public static int[] Add2Numbers(int a, int b)
{
  if (a < 0 || b < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("a or b", "One or more arguments are lesser than 0"):

  int[] aDigits = GetDigits(a);
  int[] bDigits = GetDigits(b);

  int size = aDigits.Length;
  int carry = 0;

  if (size != bDigits.Length) throw new InvalidOperationException("Numbers have different number of digits");

  int[] sumDigits = new int[aDigits.Length + 1]; // + 1 for a final carry as the leftmost digit.

  for (int j = size - 1; j >= 0; j--)
  {
    int sum = aDigits[j] + bDigits[j] + carry;
    sumDigits[j + 1] = sum % 10;
    carry = sum / 10;
  }
  sumDigits[0] += carry;

  return sumDigits;
}

static int[] GetDigits(int number)
{
  List<int> digits = new List<int>();

  while (number > 0)
  {
    digits.Add(number % 10);
    number = number / 10;
  }

  return digits.Reverse<int>().ToArray();
}
```

---

Or if it's all about getting the job done:

```
static int[] Add2Numbers(int a, int b)
{
  if (a < 0 || b < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("a or b", "One or more arguments are lesser than 0"):

  const int numBase = 10;
  int carry = 0;

  IEnumerable<int> adder()
  {
    while (a > 0 || b > 0)
    {
      int sum = (a % numBase) + (b % numBase) + carry;
      yield return sum % numBase;
      carry = sum / numBase;
      a /= numBase;
      b /= numBase;
    }

    if (carry > 0)
      yield return carry;
  }

  return adder().Reverse().ToArray();
}
```